# How to disable ctrl+esc shortcut in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Currently in a game I'm playing I'd like to crouch with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and go to the menu with <kbd>esc</kbd>. I however can't since this opens the start menu and takes me out of the game.

I'd like to disable the shortcut in Windows but still be able to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>esc</kbd> in a game. Because of this I can't simply block <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> with a hotkey remapper.

Comment: You may use a keyboard mapper like [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to block Ctrl+Esc, but with some multi-player games using such a products can get you black-listed.

Comment: This is not a valid solution, as I still need to press ctrl and escape in the game. I don't want to block that key.

Comment: So what do you want to happen when pressing both? If Esc is passed to Windows while Ctrl is pressed, you already know the result. You must cancel one of the two.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if it still valid. But you can use Power Toys' Keyboard Manager and disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> (or any other shortcut) in here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried this but I have not found a way to block the Windows shortcut with it while still allowing passthrough to apps.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Autohotkey, then create a file that contains:

```
^escape::
return
```

Answer (score -1):

Ctrl+Esc is hard coded into powershell. You could remap the specific Ctrl key you use to function like a different key.

Comment: PowerShell has nothing to do with this. Explorer is the *shell* and not PowerShell